How do i make Enemy Pathways on my procedurally generated terrain, for my Tower Defense Game?
Wassup guys. I want to ask for guidance on how to make waypoints for my enemies to reach my tower. The terrain I made for the game is procedurally generated on runtime, and players can spawn their tower anywhere on the terrain. Now I have no idea how I can make pathways for enemies to get to the tower, so I would appreciate it if you could give me ideas on how to please. I would also like to make multiple pathways also, so the enemies don't seem robotic... Thank you!
I Have not done anything yet. I am hoping you guys can set me in the right direction.

have you considered navmesh?

I allow users / "designers" to "tap out" (touch / mouse) waypoints / route points on a map; and which then get saved as a route (in a collection). At run time, these route points get loaded in a queue, and the units travel by consuming route points from the queue. Single units get their own queue, while a "leader" would consume the queue on behalf of (grouped) units marching in line; with following units consuming the waypoint of the previous unit. (Follow / pursuit pattern). In your case, you would prebuild routes and limit tower "generation" to nodes in your "path graph", that you created.

assuming you have a 2d grid as base for your pathing, your units do not need their own queue, just an indexer into a "globally" stored path. anyways, to answer your question, i had good results with just flood fill pathfinding for a towerdefense game where you can maze.

@yes start at either spawn or goal. assign 1. pick all reachable cells around it, assign 2 (= +1). pick all reachable cells, assign +1 again. rinse repeat until you found goal or spawn (depending on where you started from) if you run out of cells before that, there is no path. if you calculate that while the player wantts to place his tower, you can make sure there always is a valid path. (careful tho, depending on mapsize it may not be able to calculate within one frame, so do it either asyncronously or in a coroutine)

One thing you might look into is various procedural path generation algorithms, such as maze algorithms. This way you can generate procedural paths all around your procedural terrain. You would then have the enemies move along those paths towards the destination. An algorithm you can use for that could be something like A-star pathfinding.
The reason tower defense games take place on grid like levels is so pathfinding is easy. A-star is a grid based path finding system, so it works well. Gerry Schmitz's comment is another example of a good way to do it. The benefit of using the maze algorithms is that you can generate some interesting and dynamic paths on a grid like plane on top of your procedural terrain so that you can still maintain that feature.
If you really want to avoid a grid based system, you might be able to look into recast vision. You can have the enemy's base movement be towards the target. Then, have a series of ray's be cast out to form a view field that can detect towers, the emeries will be programmed to avoid the towers if it gets to close to it. A simple way would be compare the angle of the tower to the enemy and have it turn away from it. This will allow you to have the towers placed anywhere and the enemies to have "custom" paths.

Well, there are several solutions for this task.
1- You can use the navigation system in Unity to send your enemies toward the target location. First, set up your terrain with the navigation system to define walkable and non-walkable areas. There are plenty of tutorials available on the internet and YouTube.
2- You can create the path manually and tell your enemies which path to take to attack your castle. In the first method, the navigation system automatically selects the shortest path to reach the target, but in this method, you can assign any path to any enemy and have them choose a path randomly.
To do this, you just need to create an array of path points:
public Transform[] path1Point;
public Transform[] path2Point;

Then, assign this array in the editor.
Note: Make sure to add the path points to the array in order, starting with point 0, then point 1, point 2, and so on until the last point.
You can then determine that the enemy randomly follows one of the paths. Create an array of positions for the random path and assign it:
Transform[] randomPath = path1Point;
if (Random.Range(0, 2) == 1)
    randomPath = path2Point;
Vector3[] randomPathPoints = new Vector3[randomPath.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < randomPath.Length; i++)
{
    randomPathPoints[i] = randomPath[i].position;
}

Now you have selected a random path for the enemy, and you just need to tell the enemy to move toward the target using this path.
You can instruct them to first move toward the first member of the random path array, and when they reach that point, they should move to the second member, then the third, and continue this way until they reach the castle.
This code hasn't been tested, but it should work theoretically:
public float moveSpeed = 0.05f;
public Transform[] path1Point;
public Transform[] path2Point;
private Vector3[] randomPathPoints;

private Vector3 targetPos;
private int _currentPointPathIndex = 0;

void Start()
{
    Transform[] randomPath = path1Point;
    if (Random.Range(0, 2) == 1)
        randomPath = path2Point;
    randomPathPoints = new Vector3[randomPath.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < randomPath.Length; i++)
    {
        randomPathPoints[i] = randomPath[i].position;
    }

    targetPos = randomPathPoints[_currentPointPathIndex];
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPos) > 0.5f)
    {
        // move to targetPos
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, moveSpeed);
        transform.LookAt(targetPos);
    }
    else
    {
        if (_currentPointPathIndex < randomPathPoints.Length - 1)
            _currentPointPathIndex++;
        targetPos = randomPathPoints[_currentPointPathIndex];
    }
}

